# Как через cURL передать текст (форматом json) и файл

Tags: java, http, post, curl

У меня есть такой запрос:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/test4
     -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
     -d '{"login":"my_login","password":"my_password"}'
```

Мой сервер на java обрабатывает его таким кодом:

```
    //Working way1
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test4", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String doSomething(@RequestBody String requestBodyString) {
        System.out.println("requestBodyString: "+requestBodyString);
        System.out.println("Stop");
        return "working way";
    }
```

Получается я через cURL по HTTP передаю текст в виде json, которы обрабатывается в контроллере в сервере java.

---

При этом хочется добиться такой цели: добавить в запрос отправку файл. Подскажите как это можно сделать? Пока смотрю в сторону формирования multipart request состоящего из частей, но не нашел подходящего решения. Если кто использует такой, подскажите пожалуйста, что можно придумать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

В таком виде действительно придется формировать multipart/mixed MIME.

Как вариант рассмотрите передачу того что у вас в json через доп. заголовки, тогда можно будет просто отправлять файл без формирования mime